# Why won't my Settings.bundle update when I create an Enterprise Build with xcodebuild and xcrun?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild

Have been running a scripted build without problems for a few months now instead of using XCode to do it. When I create a build with XCode, that build has the up to date version of the Settings.bundle.

Here's the key commands:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Proj_Name.xcworkspace -sdk "iOS 6.0" -scheme Proj_Name CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" 
xcodebuild -workspace Proj_Name.xcworkspace -sdk "iOS 6.0" -scheme Proj_Name CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" archive
xcodebuild -workspace Proj_Name.xcworkspace -sdk "iOS 6.0" -scheme Proj_Name CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" -configuration release

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/Proj_Name.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/Proj_Name.ipa" --sign "$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" --embed "${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}"
```

Am I missing a command to rebuild the Settings.bundle or something of that nature?